# Min/Max timestamp follow by specific date

Tags: sql, teradata, minmax

Table consists of the following:

```
+------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID   | Date           | Timestamp                            |
+------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 01-01-2020     | 01-01-2020 10:00:00                  |
| 1    | 06-01-2020     | 06-01-2020 23:00:00                  |
| 1    | 03-02-2020     | 03-02-2020 10:00:00                  |
| 2    | 06-01-2020     | 06-01-2020 12:49:00                  |
| 2    | 07-03-2020     | 07-03-2020 10:51:00                  |
| 3    | 23-01-1992     | 23-01-1992 09:00:00                  |
| 3    | 23-01-1992     | 23-01-1992 10:00:00                  |
+------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I would like to get the ID with minimum timestamp date of '06-01-2020', the answer should be ID #2

```
SELECT

ID,
MIN(Timestamp)

FROM Table
WHERE Date = '06-01-2020'
GROUP BY ID
```

My understanding of the above will filter the date first before getting the minimum timestamp which gives an incorrect result of ID #1 and #2. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try first finding the minimum values across the entire table, then restrict to the date of interest:

```
SELECT ID, min_timestamp
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, MIN(Timestamp) AS min_timestamp
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID
) t
WHERE Date = '2020-06-01';
```

Comment: Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: @IcySkullz The subquery which uses `MIN` does a query over the entire unfiltered table to find the absolute earliest timestamp.  This happens independently of the rest of your query, so this gets around the problem with filtering in the `WHERE` clause to just one date.

Comment: May I know whether the min timestamp is associated with each ID?

Comment: You just changed your question.  Please let us know if the current version would be the final edit.

Comment: Yes, the current version should be the final edit, I forgot to include GROUPBY previously

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want two conditions:

- `MIN(timestamp)` per id
- `ID` that have records on a particular date

You can `HAVING`:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Timestamp)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '2020-06-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

This aggregates by `id` and returns the minimum timestamp.  It then filters the ids so only the ones that have a date of 2020-06-01.

If you `'2020-06-01'` is the most recent date in the table you could simplify that to:

```
HAVING MAX(Date) = '2020-06-01'
```

Comment: I am not familiar with how HAVING works. This is my understanding of your solution: 
Retrieve all ID that has '2020-06-01' and get the earliest date for these ID. Please correct my if I misunderstood

Comment: I have edited by post for better understanding. May check with you whether the solution will return ID #2?

Answer (score 0):

This returns IDs with a minimum timestamp on 06-01-2020

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MIN(Timestamp)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING min(Date) = date '2020-01-06'
```

or without the date column

```
HAVING cast(min(timestamp as date)) = date '2020-01-06'
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. I am trying to visualise how HAVING works. If we use GROUP BY and only indicate ID column, will the table be only left with the ID and the aggregate column? Then how will the system filter for the Date column using having?

Comment: HAVING filters the result of an aggregation, similar to WHERE filtering the result of the FROM. It can access only columns in GROUP BY and aggregated columns, that's why `HAVING min(date)` works, but not `HAVING date`.